# android Studio "Common part can be extracted from 'if' "

Tags: android-studio, if-statement

In Android Studio I created a code where I declare

```
int variablename = 1
```

I later perform `if (string.contains("hello")){ variablename = 0 }`

and later  `if ( variablename == 0 ) { ...do stuff.. }`

but android studio says : "Common part can be extracted from 'if'"

What does that means ?

is it a problem ?

if yes, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a warning you are receiving from Android Studio that informs you about a change you can make to optimize your code. This specific warning usually indicates that there's an unecessary piece of code which can be removed without affecting the existing functionality, thus achieving better readability.

In general, Android Studio will provide you with a lot of warnings that help you optimize your code and it's good practice to try and resolve them.

When you get a warning on a piece of code it is highlighted in yellow and if you hover with your mouse cursor over it, a solution will be suggested to you. Alternatively, use shortcut "Alt+Enter" if you use Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks, android studio proposed me to change it for switch case ;)

Comment: Funfact ; after changing it to switch android studio tells me too few case label... I'll add some later

Comment: In Android Studio we trust :D . Yeah, if you have too few case labels, a switch statement may not be the best option.

Comment: I don't see a connection between clones of conditions and a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this warning means that there is duplicate code for different conditions, for example:

```
if(condition)
{
    a=1;
    b=3;
}
else
{
    c=2;
    a=1;
}
```

If you move `a=1` out of the if statement the warning disappears.

If your question really contains all relevant code the warning probably means that 'variablename' is completely unnecessary because you don't really use it and could do everything in the first if statement.